# How to get Django Admin Log Entries from last hour?

Tags: python, django

In standard Django, the `django_admin_log` table shows the date and time of changes to the database entries in the `action_time` column:

```
sqlite> select * from django_admin_log;
1|2021-07-18 21:34:01.312033|6|[6] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Phy"]}}]|8|1|2
2|2021-07-18 21:47:02.451262|6|[6] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Phy"]}}]|8|1|2
3|2021-07-18 22:09:42.689067|6|[6] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[]|8|1|2
4|2021-07-18 22:09:52.292117|6|[6] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Phy"]}}]|8|1|2
5|2021-07-19 12:21:57.715529|9|[9] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Phy"]}}]|8|1|2
6|2021-07-19 12:35:22.504624|9|[9] (1960-03-20) Pat Three|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Phy"]}}]|8|1|2
... more entries
```

I'd like to query the entries based on some comparison, I assumed a naive ansatz could work with `filter` (as is possible in SQLite itself), so I'd like the Python equivalent of the below SQL statement:

```
sqlite> select * from django_admin_log where action_time > '2021-07-20';                    
12|2021-07-20 16:34:00.114548|13|[13] (1960-01-20) Pat Changed|[{"changed": {"fields": ["Family name"]}}]|8|1|2
```

I thought it would be something along the lines of

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
last_hour_changes = LogEntry.objects.filter(last_hour > action_time)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [***`gte`***--[Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#gte) lookup as,

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

last_hour = timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
last_hour_changes = LogEntry.objects.filter(action_time__gte=last_hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a [**`Now`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#now) which will use the "clock" of the database. Furthermore an advantage is that if you use this as `queryset` in a view, you do not need to override `get_queryset`, since the timestamp is already set to `Now()`:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Task.objects.filter(deadline__gte=Now()-timedelta(hours=1))
```